# .csv loading repeats all entries from one column in every cell

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am attempting to load a given csv file with the folowing structure:
[image: .csv sample]

Then, I'd like to join all the words with the same "Sent_ID" into one row, with the following code:

```
train = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
# Create a dataframe of sentences.
sentence_df = pd.DataFrame(train["Sent_ID"].drop_duplicates(), columns=["Sent_ID", "Sentence", "Target"])
for _, row in train.iterrows():
    print(str(row["Word"]))
    sentence_df.loc[sentence_df["Sent_ID"] == row["Sent_ID"], ["Sentence"]] = str(row["Word"])
```

However, the result of the print(str(row["Word"])) is:

```
Name: Word, Length: 4543833, dtype: object
0                     Obesity
1                          in
2                        Low-
3                         and
4               Middle-Income
5                   Countries
...
```

i.e every single word in the column, for any given row. This occurs for all rows.
Printing the entire row gives:

```
id                                                        89
Doc_ID                                                     1
Sent_ID                                                    4
Word       0                     Obesity\n1              ...
tag                                                        O
Name: 88, dtype: object
```

This again suggests that every element of the "Word" column is present in each cell. (The 88th entry is not "Obesity\n1" in the .csv file.

I have tried changing the quoting argument in the read_csv function, as well as manually inserting the headers in the names argument, to no avail.

How do I ensure each Dataframe entry only contains its own word?

I've added a pastebin with some of the samples [here](https://pastebin.com/5ffgKnYG) (the pastebin will expire a week after this edit).

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do with your code, so whats is goal with this csv after reading it in pandas?

Comment: This code will be used to classify sentences using LSTM. I'm trying to have a single row for each sentence, whereas the .csv file gives each word its own row. The original rows have "Sent_ID" which is the same for each word (i.e. row in the .csv) in the sentence.

Comment: The code of @Aravind works for me doing what you want? If you want I can answer and show example.

Comment: That would be nice, as using that solution doesn't seem to work for me. Each row of the resultant Dataframe still has every single word from the .csv file in the "Word" column, rather than individual sentences.

Comment: See my answer, does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @Aravinds answer, OP wanted a working example:

```
from io import StringIO

csv = StringIO('''
<paste csv snippet here>
'''

df = pd.read_csv(csv)

# Print first 5 rows
print(df.head())
   id  Doc_ID  Sent_ID           Word tag
0   1       1        1        Obesity   O
1   2       1        1             in   O
2   3       1        1           Low-   O
3   4       1        1            and   O
4   5       1        1  Middle-Income   O
```

Now we have the data loaded as a `pandas.DataFrame` We can use the method to combine the words into sentences.

```
df = df.groupby('Sent_ID').Word.apply(' '.join).reset_index()
print(df)
     Sent_ID                                               Word
0          1  Obesity in Low- and Middle-Income Countries : ...
1          2  We have reviewed the distinctive features of e...
2          3  Obesity is rising in every region of the world...
3          4  In LMICs , overweight is higher in women compa...
4          5  Overweight occurs alongside persistent burdens...
5          6  Changes in the global diet and physical activi...
6          7  Emerging risk factors include environmental co...
7          8  Data on effective strategies to prevent the on...
8          9  Expanding the research in this area is a key p...
9         10                                 MICROCEPHALIA VERA
10        11  Excellent reproducibility of laser speckle con...
11        12  We compared the inter-day reproducibility of p...
12        13  We also tested whether skin blood flow assessm...
13        14  Skin blood flow was evaluated during PORH and ...
14        15  Data are expressed as cutaneous vascular condu...
15        16  Reproducibility is expressed as within subject...
16        17  Twenty-eight healthy participants were enrolle...
17        18  The reproducibility of the PORH peak CVC was b...
18        19  Inter-day reproducibility of the LTH plateau w...
19        20  Finally , we observed significant correlation ...
20        21  The recently developed LSCI technique showed v...
21        22  Moreover , we showed significant correlation b...
22        23  However , more data are needed to evaluate the...
23        24  Positive inotropic action of cholinesterase on...
24        25  The putative chloride channel hCLCA2 has a sin...
25        26  Calcium-activated chloride channel ( CLCA ) pr...
26        27  Genetic and electrophysiological studies have ...
27        28  The human CLCA2 protein is expressed as a 943-...
28        29  Earlier investigations of transmembrane geomet...
29        30  However , analysis by the more recently derive...
```

Comment: That's perfect, but the first block of code is where I have my issue since my "Word" column is not working correctly. That's my main issue.
Edit: My issue seems to have fixed itself after a restart, so this answer works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby()`

```
df = df.groupby('Sent_ID')['Word'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

You can group by multiple columns as a list. Like so 
`df.groupby(['Doc_ID','Sent_ID','tag'])`

Comment: That's good for when the Dataframe has the data in the correct format, but my issue is that every entry in the "Word" column contains all of the words in the "Word" column of the .csv file.

Comment: Can you add the csv as snippet so I can copy paste and test? I'll look at it tomorrow. Have to go now.

Comment: I couldn't understand snippets so I added some of the .csv file to a pastebin. Hopefully that's sufficient. Thanks for looking into this.